# Combobox in radgrid - Selected value is not written to the db

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox, telerik

This combo box is in an asp.net page and the intention is to bind it to a nvarchar(50).
The user select one of the values and then update the DB.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("inBudgetTT") %>'>
  <Items>
   <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="In Budget" />
   <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Not In Budget" />       
  </Items>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

The problem: doesn't matter what I select, it is never written in the DB. Any hint on how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use the SelectedIndexChanged event to update your database: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-server-side-selectedindexchanged.html. The SelectedValue property only indicates what the control should show as a selected item.